# Removing some tags with jquery in contenteditable div

Tags: jquery, tags, contenteditable

i have a contenteditable div. when a user paste text in it. It comes with html tags and i would like to remove all tags except b,i,u,blockquote,h3 tags.

How can i achieve that?
Thank you for your helps.

Comment: Please read [ask] and than eventually provide us some code with a [mcve]. If you're still not clear how this website works make sure to  take a [tour].

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ignoreTags = "b, i, u, blockquote, h3";


$("[contenteditable]").on({
  paste : function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(this).find("*").not(ignoreTags).contents().unwrap();
    }.bind(this), 0);
  }
});
```

```css
p{color: blue;}
[contenteditable]{background:#eee;padding:16px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>H2. Unwrap me.</h2>
<h3>H3. Keep me.</h3>
<blockquote>blockquote</blockquote>
<p>Unwrap Paragraph but keep <b>bold</b> and <i>italic</i></p>

<div contenteditable>pasteHere</div>
```